# Change rsync language in Cygwin to German

Tags: cygwin

In my Cygwin environment LANG is set to 'de_DE.UTF-8' and many things are German like gcc and bash.

But rsync is still English.

Is it possible to change this?

Comment: Really not sure if rsync is translated _at all_. Are you using a UI for it or the cli command?

Comment: @somega : Just being curious: Are there **any** Cygwin utilities (except plain bash and gcc), which are fully translated to German? Even with, for instance, `ls -§`, I get _unknown option_ as response (i.e. in English).

Comment: If translation is not provided upstream, it is not available in a cygwin package.

Comment: Ok, thank you. As conclusion I can say a translation is not available.